# Styling the Paypal page

Tags: paypal

I have a Paypal 'buy now' button on a site and was wondering if I can use some custom CSS on the Paypal page to change background etc. I've had a look through the Paypal developer documentation but it's all stuff about APIs and integrating carts etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the PayPal checkout page design via the CSS . However you can customize some of the features like border color , header image , logo image etc by passing the display related variables that you can find at below url :

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI0709B